# Why only a.out is being created everytime when I make different programs in directory?

Tags: c, linux

I am learning C in Linux Mint, so I made a directory in which I place my programs. Whenever I compile a program, everytime `a.out` is being over-written with the new compiled program.
For ex. To compile a `hello.c` file I run command: `cc hello.c`, Now this program will create `a.out`, but I want it to be `hello.out`
Why is it?
How can I compile so that hello.c should create hello.out file?

Answer (score 4):

> Why only a.out is being created everytime when I make different programs in directory?

Because that's the default behavior of your compiler.

> How can I compile so that hello.c should create hello.out file?

In general, refer to the documentation for the compiler you're using, which will tell you how to do this.

Assuming you're using `gcc` or similar, it's the `-o` option:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello.out
```

Comment: Why everytime a.out is created? Is it Unix tradition?

Comment: because you haven't specify the output filename

Comment: @Pr4njal: Again: *"Because that's the default behavior of your compiler."* Yes, I think it dates back many, many years to the earliest `cc` on Unix. Remember that you can list several C files on the command line and have them all compiled into one program. (FWIW, I can tell you that even in 1990, Borland's C compiler for DOS had a different default [based on the first source filename, I think].)

Answer (score 2):

Default execution in **Unix/Linux** is `a.out` file. If you create your own executable then compile program like:

```
cc hello.c -o hello.out
./hello.out // manually created executable file
```

**or**

```
cc hello.c -o hello
./hello // manually created executable file
```

**Unix/Linux** doesn't care about extensions. `-o hello` basically your suggested name for the executable file that `gcc` would create.

> Why every time a.out is created?

`a.out` remains the **default output** file name for executables created by certain **compilers/linkers** when **no output name is specified**, even though these executables are no longer in the `a.out` format.

Please see the wiki page of [a.out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out).

Answer (score 0):

Share your compilation command.
In the compilation command you can mention what the name of the output binary file, like: "gcc hello.c -o hello" then the binary file name will be (hello) because you mention after flag "-o" that you want to name the output file by the name "hello".
If you don't add the flag "-o" with a name, then the default name for the binary file is "a.out".